# Bootstrap css block among each other

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3, grid

this is my situation with bootstrap I put 2 blocks next to each other:

class="col-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6"

[image]

At a certain point when we reach 1000px I want the boxes to be among each other like this:

[image]

this now only happens when i reach 576px,
does someone how i can accomplish this.

code:

```
<div class="col-sm-6">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-enable">
        <div class="modal-content modal-dialog-enable" >
            <div class="modal-header modal-dialog-enable">

            </div>

            <div class="modal-body modal-dialog-enable">
                <p>

                </p>


            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer  modal-dialog-enable">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

THX a lot

Comment: please add your code snippet. thanks

Comment: Overwrite the `float` property for the columns then below that breakpoint …

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can read this information:
[image]

"At a certain point when we reach 1000px I want the boxes to be among each other like this." 
1000px belongs medium, and now display 2 columns (each has 50% width). 
 
Way 1: Rewrite class name

```html
<div class="col-6 col-sm-6 col-md-12 col-lg-6">First column</div>
<div class="col-6 col-sm-6 col-md-12 col-lg-6">Second column</div>
```

Way 2: Overwrite default bootstrap.min.css

```css
@media (min-width: 992px)
.col-md-6 {
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: @user3356007
1250px belongs Large:
`<div class="col-6 col-sm-6 col-md-12 col-lg-12">First column</div>
<div class="col-6 col-sm-6 col-md-12 col-lg-12">Second column</div>`